# Проект с высокой посещаемостью — архитектура. Фреймворк или самопис? Узкие места YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii, kohana

Никак не могу определиться на чем писать крупный проект. Проект из себя представляет нечто вроде социальной сети. Реализовываться будет на php, mysql. Основные нагрузки будут на базу в момент общения пользователей. Все примерно как вконтакте, друзья и собственно переписка, и личные сообщения. Я начал писать свой mvc фреймворк, получилось что то похожее на kohana-yii. В нем мне предельно все ясно, я продумал что маршрутизация будет хранится в мэмкэше, некоторые постоянные данные так же для максимальной производительности. Потом скорее всего мощности 1 сервера не будет хватать и нужно будет распределять базу данных по серверам, а я хз как это сделать.

И вот я задумался - а может не париться с разработкой фреймворка и взять yii или другой готовый фреймворк. Подходит ли YII для такого проекта? Какие узкие места в нем которые будут сказываться на производительности? Есть ли какая то альтернатива? Большое количество чатов для общения между пользователями - где хранить данные, в mysql или? Выдержит ли mysql? Подходит ли для этого php?

Answer (score 3):

под большие проекты я бы посоветовал использовать: Symfony 2, Zend, Kohana.
Yii больше подойдет для средних проектов.

Имхо.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы ни в коем случае не использовал Yii. Первая версия выйдет большим боком с PSR-совместимостью (т.е. будет все-таки самопис) и многими wtf-моментами, вторая получше, но я с ней уже успел натерпеться и не хочу даже трогать. Symfony мне очень нравится с точки зрения разделения prod/dev версий, настоящей проработки и кэширования, Phalcon я бы рассматривал как потенциально скоростной вариант. Самопис изначально провален по той причине, что за те же стартовые деньги придется поддерживать и самописный фреймворк, и приложение (писать их вместе единым целым толком не получится).

Все-таки еще скажу пару слов про PSR: только он и внешние библиотеки позволят расщепить код на составные части и улучшать именно нужные (а поддержка и ускорение внешних либ на 95% будут осуществляться другими разрабами), не говоря уж о том, сколько кода придется не писать.

upd 2 Ну и от SPOF в архитектуре ни один фреймворк не спасет, это стоит помнить.

Comment: Yii2 очень сложный тем, что разрешает очень многое. Вы скорее всего его не правильно приготовили.

Comment: @Nepster, я бы все-таки использовал термины "исчадие ада" и "фреймоврк, внедряющий самые худшие возможные практики".

Comment: например ? Думаю Александр с Вами поспорил бы.

Comment: @Nepster я уже с ним спорил. Про исчадие ада, конечно, перебрал, но этот фреймворк реально ответственен за кривые мозги части российских девелоперов и, поверьте, "сложный тем, что разрешает многое" - это вам кажется. Стоит поменять название столбца в базе данных, как уже нужно половину приложения пересобирать.

Comment: Это типа привет доктрина ? Ну тут может быть, хотя я думал мы пойдете дальше и скажете про архитектуру и связанность.

Comment: Когда нужно пересобирать половину приложения - это и есть про архитектуру и связность

Comment: Ну тут опять таки много споров и моментов. Если нужно переименовать столбец, глобальная замена сделает это мгновенно. Проблема только в миграциях, в yii на каждый чих нужно создавать класс миграций, но это уже другой вопрос.  Но к примеру актив рекорд куда удобнее и менее баганный чем доктрина. А сам yii2 куда быстрее чем симфони2. Нет супер идеала, везде есть свои минусы и плюсы. Сам сам щас пишу на yii2, но чувствую кое-какой дискомфорт.

Comment: *Если нужно переименовать столбец, глобальная замена сделает это мгновенно.* - попробуйте переименовать какой-нибудь `id`, на котором даже рефакторинг idea завалится и предложит пообновлять все комментарии, и не говорите больше таких вещей.

Comment: что-то мне кажется, вы нашли проблему там, где ее нет.

Comment: ну что вы, никогда с этим не сталкивался в практике

Comment: на самом деле, я сталкивался с  насколько извращенными задачами, что лучше их не вспоминать. Возможно не во всех я испытывал проблемы. Что касается yii2, эта штука отлично подходит для быстрой и удобной разработки любого проекта, однако очень важно его правильно приготовить, если вы свернете не туда, то потом уже не выберитесь. Хотя честно говоря работая 2 года с yii2 у меня появляется некий дискомфорт.  Что касается симфони2, конечно архитектура там приличная и как отдельные компоненты это здорово, но как сам фраэмворк достаточно медленный в dev версии и разрабатывать мне не удобно.

Answer (score 2):

используйте Yii, подходит. Остальные задачи решайте по мере наступления.

Comment: @z_coder, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал yii. Тем более что у них есть неплохой рецепт на сайте http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/highload

Comment: Эта статья применима к любому веб-приложению

Comment: yii1 это мусор, не советуйте его пожалуйста в 2015 году.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать лучше тот фреймворк, с которым Вы хорошо знакомы. Помните - не фреймворк справляется с нагрузками, а архитектура. [Много полезной информации о Хайлоаде](http://ruhighload.com/sitemap).